# Who you'll work with doesn't display correctly on company page

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-talent

It seems that companies page doesn't work correctly, The part **Who you'll work with** doesn't work anymore, I can see the error **Uncaught TypeError: Careers.using is not a function** in the console

[image: company_bug]

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/hippo)

Comment: it seems the bug has just yet been fixed